# javascript function access ios native features

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

This situation: Like PhoneGap, I want to define and call an inexistent JavaScript function, which need to access ios features. e.g.,

javascript code:

```
function onClickButton(){
    toModule(true, true, "title1", 1);
}
```

I want to access iOS features through the function toModule. But How? Can you tell me?

PS: I know one solution JS->iOS is by using UIWebViewDelegate's

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

but I don't want that solution, just handle the JS function toModule(...)

Answer (score 0):

From javascript(phonegap) you cant access ios native code directly instead you should use or develop a phonegap plugin that  could establish this connection .

you can find more at [Plugin Development Guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html)

Comment: Then how iOS handle the Javascript function call, besides by using UIWebViewDelegate?

Comment: yes with UIWebViewDelegate but phonegap will handle this process internally so you should not bother yourself with it .

Answer (score 0):

This is very Simple 
Step 1) Include cordova.js file in your project 
Step2) Include cordova.js in your javascript file and in your javascript file add the following code

```
    cordova.exec(
                              function successCallback() {

                              }, 
function errorHandler(err) {
                              },
'Login', 'callLogin', [param]);
                              }
```

here Login is the name of native class and callLogin is function in Login class, param is the array of parameters you want to send to native file

Step3) Goto config.xml and this

```
<feature name="Login">
        <param name="ios-package" value="Login"/>
    </feature>
```

Step4)

```
- (void)Login:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
    { // this is the native function, which is being called from javascript file, do your work here
     }
```

Step5) If you want to send any data back to js file from native you need to write the below code.

NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"callJsFunction(parameters)];
   [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

callJsFunction() is the name of the js function which you want to call from native.(you can send string only)

Step6) To fetch value from native to js you need to write callJsFunction(parameters) in js file. write below function in js file

callJsFunction(parameters)
  {
   }

this is the complete process for calling native function from js and js from native class.